# Why do we care about the compactness of the support of a measure?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-calculus

We often have the condition of "compact support" in theorems. Why is it important? Are there any special properties relies on it? For example, the random variable is bounded if its distribution has compact support.

I have two questions here: 1. why is the random variable bounded if its distribution has compact support?
                           2.Are there any other porperties relied on the                                     compactness of support like this? Why we often have to add this condition?

This is my first time to ask questions. Thank you very much!

Comment: are you familiar with what a compact set is and any important theorems relating to them? What have you learned about support in the context of probability thus far?

Comment: In real analysis, compact means a closed subset of some interval $[a,b]$ (or of $[a,b]^n \subset \mathbb{R}^n$). If $f$ is bounded and $\mu$ is a compactly supported measure then $\int_\mathbb{R} f(x)d\mu(x)$ is always finite. Thus if a real random variable $X$ is compactly supported, then there is no convergence problem when computing $\mathbb{E}[f(X)] = \int_\mathbb{R} f(x)d\mathbb{P}(X \le x)$. It is because a Gaussian random variable $W$ is not compactly supported that $\mathbb{E}[e^{X^4}]$ doesn't converge.

Comment: I only know the definition of the compact set. And I know that it is equivalent to "complete and totally bounded" in metric spaces. About support, I know its definition only. I think my problem is that I only read the words of definitions but lack the deeper understanding of their intuitive meaning. @BrevanEllefsen

Comment: Aha! I got it. You are right. Thank you very much!@reuns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that a compact on the real numbers is close and bounded. If the distribution support of a r.v. is bounded, this implies that outside a bounded set the random variable takes values with probability zero. Equivalently, it is bounded with probability 1. However, the importance of the compact support depends of the particular theorem you are interested in, this is not strictly necessary and there are a myriad of commonly used and important r.v. without compact support.

I am not sure what you mean by "compactness of the support of a measure". But maybe checking some of the properties of compact spaces ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space)) would help you understanding why is it required for your specific case.

As this is your first question I would also recommend you to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your chances to get an answer on what you need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: $X$ is a compactly supported random variable is the same as $\mathbb{P}( \ |X| \ <\ C \ )  = 1$ for some $C$.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is helpful. And this webset is so cool. It is such a nice place to learn mathematics!